Matlab inputparser catches wrong input with the same leading characters
This test function returns the square of the input, and can add an optional offset when supplied as a name-value input.
function out=test_parser(a,varargin)

    % parse inputs
    parser=inputParser;
    parser.KeepUnmatched=true;
    addRequired(parser,'a',@isnumeric);
    addParameter(parser,'offset',0);

    parse(parser,a,varargin{:});
    offset=parser.Results.offset;

    out=a^2+offset;
end

>> test_parser(2)
>> 4
>> test_parser(2,`offset`,1)
>> 5

Now say we don't supply offset, but a different name-value input with the same initial letters as offset. This should be ignored due to parser.KeepUnmatched=true. But it's being caught as if it's offset, and added to the output:
>> test_parser(2,'off',1)
>> 5

This is an actual problem for me because in my code, I sometimes have such a function called by another function, with a different input with the same leading characters, that should be ignored.
This seems like an egregious mistake, for matlab's inputParser to catch any variable that has the same leading characters. Or am I getting something wrong?

Being able to abbreviate these names is a long-standing feature of MATLAB. Glad you found out how to turn it off.

I realized that this is happening because Matlab's inputParser does partial matching by default. To prevent this, we need to set PartialMatching=false.
